# Bluetooth pairing without passkey

Tags: visual-c++, passwords, core-bluetooth

I am going to develope a application in VC++ for bluetooth communication.My aim is to pair two bluetooth devices without the passkey communication.For my application am using the BluetoothAPI.
Anybody can help me to complete my task by providing the code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i have 2 Bluetooth
1. PC dongle and 2. Mouse Bluetooth Device of same make 
 
in normal installation we goto Control Panel and do add device ,this device directly gets added in the system and pair with each other without using any key.
 
i want to automate this by getting event from the OS that the device is inserted to the system so that i will start my exe,dll..which will install device without giving control panel window?
 
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string BTMac = "00:01:58:08:3D:ED";

BluetoothAddress BTAddress;

BluetoothClient BTClient = new BluetoothClient();

BluetoothEndPoint BTEndPoint;

Guid spguid = BluetoothService.SerialPort;

BTAddress = BluetoothAddress.Parse(BTMac);

BTEndPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(BTAddress, spguid);

try

{

BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(BTAddress, strDevicePassKey);

Application.DoEvents();

BTClient = new BluetoothClient();

BTClient.Connect(BTEndPoint);

return true;

}

catch { return false; }
```

Use a key common to both PC and device in place of `strDevicePassKey`.