# Pairing to a serial to Bluetooth dongle(blank passkey) from android

Tags: android

I’m trying to pair with a device that’s got no UI and a serial to Bluetooth dongle with my android phone. The device does not require a passkey … but the dialog on my phone opens and asked for a passkey to connect. I have tried 0000, 1234, 1111 also adding a character and then deleting it and click on ok… pairing fails.

I have also tried code using the setPin method but the same happens. What would the devices pin be that I need to pass in to the setPin function if it reuires no pin?

I have stumbled across this post and it seems like it could work :

[Bluetooth pairing without passkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292835/bluetooth-pairing-without-passkey/11626336#11626336)

My question in this example is, what will the strDevicePassKey variable value be in BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(BTAddress, strDevicePassKey); if the device requires no passkey or a blank passkey?

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52529